# Deal with [google-maps-sdk-ios] and [google-maps-ios]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I believe that [google-maps-sdk-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-sdk-ios) and [google-maps-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-ios) actually mean the same thing.

Some stats:

- [google-maps-sdk-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-sdk-ios) - 1,164 questions
- [google-maps-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-ios) - 29 questions, no wiki, no excerpt

I suggest to add [google-maps-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-ios) as a synonym for [google-maps-sdk-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-sdk-ios), or just retag all the questions.
Also, I think it makes sense to create another synonym [google-maps-ios-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-ios-sdk) or maybe even make it a main tag, because this product is called [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start). And I've tried to find this tag by typing `google-maps-sdk-..` and failed.

Also, there is [google-maps-ios-utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-ios-utils) with 7 questions.